# Reading from boost serialized file throws exception

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to c++ coding. 
I am trying run this code on visual studios to read from boost serialized binary, and when I try to read from it, it throws exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>


using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint32_t {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
};

int main() {
    int data = 5;

    std::ofstream f("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(f);
    ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));

    uint32_t restored_info;
    std::ifstream Obj_ifstream("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ip_archive(Obj_ifstream);
    ip_archive >> restored_info;

    std::cout << "Testing " << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

**Exception:**

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::archive::archive_exception'
>   what():  input stream error

Comment: Call `f.close()` before creating `Obj_ifstream`.

Comment: If the answer helped accept and upvote please ;)

Comment: Ans helped me , thanks for that. But I am not able to up-vote, because of being a new user, reputation is below 15 points.

Comment: @PratikPatil Accept answer works aswell

Answer (score 2):

You open the inputfile stream before the output file stream is closed (you cannot open the file for read and write simultaniously). Make sure to close it first as mentioned by @rafix07 in his comment, or encapuslate the code blocks like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>


using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint32_t {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
};

int main() {
    int data = 5;

    {
        std::ofstream f("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(f);
        ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));
    }
    {
        uint32_t restored_info;
        std::ifstream Obj_ifstream("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ip_archive(Obj_ifstream);
        ip_archive >> restored_info;
        std::cout << "restored ino " << restored_info << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Testing " << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```